# How can I change every pixels in WebGL

Tags: html, canvas, webgl

When we use canvas by 2d, changing the image color can be done like below

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = "images/1.png";

img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,400,400);

    var data = imgData.data;
    for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i+=4){
        data[i]=data[i+1]=data[i+2]=(data[i]+data[i+1]+data[i+2])/3
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0)
}
```

but when I use canvas by WebGL how to do it. I can only use readPixels to read every pixels ,but don't know how to update.

Answer (score 1):

You don't generally do things like that in WebGL. Rather you only render to the canvas, you don't generally read from it.

If you want to render an image you first load that image into a texture. You can then draw that texture to the canvas supplying a shader that modifies colors as it draw.

If you want to modify the texture itself you generally create another texture, attach it to a framebuffer, and then render from the first texture into the second texture applying whatever effect you want. You can then render that second texture into the canvas.

Here's [an article with more details](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html)

Note your question sound like maybe you're new to WebGL. To do simple things in WebGL requires quite a bit of setup so I suggest you [go read some tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org/)